# Cannot execute select using pyodbc with Python 3.3.2

Tags: python-3.3, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am developing a data syncing script for a project using python 3.3.2 and pyodbc. The data that I need is coming from a sql server 2008 instance, but so far I have not been able to make any queries successfully.

I am able to establish a connection to the database server with pyodbc:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=<DSN>; UID=<uid>; PWD=<pwd>')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

The freetds and iodbc logs show a successful connection to the database server (logs included blow). However, when I try to execute a query:

```
cursor.execute('select * from <TABLE>')
```

I get this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '�'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

The iodbc and FreeTDS logs show that '??????????????????????????????' is being passed as the query. This looks to me like a unicode/encoding problem. The same pyodbc code works in a python 2.7 using the same versions of iODBC and FreeTDS, so I think this problem has something to do with the interaction between python 3.3.2 and pyodbc.

I found this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=339), but have yet to find any sort of fix or workaround. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure this one out for the past two days without much luck.

If there is any information that I have not included that would be helpful, let me know, I'll provide what I can. I do not have access to the SQL Server logs.

Environment:

Mac OSX 10.8.5
Python 3.3.2
pyodbc 3.0.7
iODBC 3.52.6  (I can't figure out how to convince pyodbc to use unixodbc on Mac)
FreeTDS 0.91

iODBC log:

```
[000000.000070]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLAllocHandle
                SQLSMALLINT       1 (SQL_HANDLE_ENV)
                SQLHANDLE         0x0 (SQL_NULL_HANDLE)
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x1007b5970

[000000.000091]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLAllocHandle with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLSMALLINT       1 (SQL_HANDLE_ENV)
                SQLHANDLE         0x0 (SQL_NULL_HANDLE)
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x1007b5970 (0x10049e350)

[000000.000110]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLSetEnvAttr
                SQLHENV           0x10049e350
                SQLINTEGER        200 (SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION)
                SQLPOINTER        0x3
                SQLINTEGER      * 4

[000000.000508]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLSetEnvAttr with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHENV           0x10049e350
                SQLINTEGER        200 (SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION)
                SQLPOINTER        0x3
                SQLINTEGER      * 4

[000000.000527]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLAllocHandle
                SQLSMALLINT       2 (SQL_HANDLE_DBC)
                SQLHANDLE         0x10049e350
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x7fff5fbff080

[000000.000545]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLAllocHandle with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLSMALLINT       2 (SQL_HANDLE_DBC)
                SQLHANDLE         0x10049e350
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x7fff5fbff080 (0x1004c3bf0)

[000000.000569]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLDriverConnectW
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLPOINTER        0x0
                SQLWCHAR        * 0x1004c3cf0
                          | ???????????????????????????????????                                  |
                SQLSMALLINT       39
                SQLWCHAR        * 0x0
                SQLSMALLINT       0
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)

[000000.000709]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLPOINTER        0x0
                SQLWCHAR        * 0x1004c3cf0
                SQLSMALLINT       39
                SQLWCHAR        * 0x0
                SQLSMALLINT       0
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)

[000000.000740]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLDriverConnect
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLPOINTER        0x0
                SQLCHAR         * 0x7fff5fbff0a0
                          | DSN=<dsn>;UID=<uid>t;PWD=<pwd>  |
                SQLSMALLINT       -3 (SQL_NTS)
                SQLCHAR         * 0x0
                SQLSMALLINT       0
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)

[000000.071429]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLDriverConnect with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLPOINTER        0x0
                SQLCHAR         * 0x7fff5fbff0a0
                SQLSMALLINT       -3 (SQL_NTS)
                SQLCHAR         * 0x0
                SQLSMALLINT       0
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)

[000000.071482]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLSetConnectAttr
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLINTEGER        102 (SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT)
                SQLPOINTER        0x0
                SQLINTEGER      * 4294967291 (SQL_IS_UINTEGER)

[000000.089380]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLSetConnectAttr with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLINTEGER        102 (SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT)
                SQLPOINTER        0x0
                SQLINTEGER      * 4294967291 (SQL_IS_UINTEGER)

[000000.089468]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetInfo
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLUSMALLINT      77 (SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbff000
                SQLSMALLINT       20
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeffe

[000000.089502]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetInfo with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLUSMALLINT      77 (SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbff000
                          | 03.50                                    |
                SQLSMALLINT       20
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeffe (5)

[000000.089529]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetInfo
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLUSMALLINT      10002 (SQL_DESCRIBE_PARAMETER)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbfeffc
                SQLSMALLINT       2
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeffe

[000000.089550]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetInfo with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLUSMALLINT      10002 (SQL_DESCRIBE_PARAMETER)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbfeffc
                          | N                                        |
                SQLSMALLINT       2
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeffe (1)

[000000.089593]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetInfo
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLUSMALLINT      111 (SQL_NEED_LONG_DATA_LEN)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbfeffc
                SQLSMALLINT       2
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeffe

[000000.089615]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetInfo with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHDBC           0x1004c3bf0
                SQLUSMALLINT      111 (SQL_NEED_LONG_DATA_LEN)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbfeffc
                          | Y                                        |
                SQLSMALLINT       2
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeffe (1)

[000000.089638]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLAllocHandle
                SQLSMALLINT       3 (SQL_HANDLE_STMT)
                SQLHANDLE         0x1004c3bf0
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x7fff5fbfeff0

[000000.089669]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLAllocHandle with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLSMALLINT       3 (SQL_HANDLE_STMT)
                SQLHANDLE         0x1004c3bf0
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x7fff5fbfeff0 (0x1004cabb0)

[000000.089686]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetTypeInfo
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       93 (SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP)

[000000.111645]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetTypeInfo with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       93 (SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP)

[000000.111684]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLFetch
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0

[000000.111711]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLFetch with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0

[000000.111724]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetData
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLUSMALLINT      3
                SQLSMALLINT       4 (SQL_C_LONG)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbfefec
                SQLLEN            4
                SQLLEN          * 0x0

[000000.111759]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetData with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLUSMALLINT      3
                SQLSMALLINT       4 (SQL_C_LONG)
                SQLPOINTER        0x7fff5fbfefec
                          | 21580870632603671                        |
                SQLLEN            4
                SQLLEN          * 0x0

[000000.111788]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetTypeInfo
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       12 (SQL_VARCHAR)

[000000.111801]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetTypeInfo with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       12 (SQL_VARCHAR)

[000000.111815]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetTypeInfo
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       -9 (SQL_WVARCHAR)

[000000.111828]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetTypeInfo with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       -9 (SQL_WVARCHAR)

[000000.111842]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetTypeInfo
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       -2 (SQL_BINARY)

[000000.111854]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetTypeInfo with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLSMALLINT       -2 (SQL_BINARY)

[000000.111869]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLFreeStmt
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_CLOSE)

[000000.132529]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLFreeStmt with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHSTMT          0x1004cabb0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_CLOSE)

[000000.132590]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLAllocHandle
                SQLSMALLINT       3 (SQL_HANDLE_STMT)
                SQLHANDLE         0x1004c3bf0
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x101373ee8

[000000.132629]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLAllocHandle with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLSMALLINT       3 (SQL_HANDLE_STMT)
                SQLHANDLE         0x1004c3bf0
                SQLHANDLE       * 0x101373ee8 (0x10045c0b0)

[000123.339614]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLFreeStmt
                SQLHSTMT          0x10045c0b0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_CLOSE)

[000123.339667]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLFreeStmt with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLHSTMT          0x10045c0b0
                SQLUSMALLINT      0 (SQL_CLOSE)

[000123.339718]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLExecDirectW
                SQLHSTMT          0x10045c0b0
                SQLWCHAR        * 0x10047a540
                          | ??????????????????????????????                                   |
                SQLINTEGER        -3 (SQL_NTS)

[000123.360756]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLExecDirectW with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
                SQLHSTMT          0x10045c0b0
                SQLWCHAR        * 0x10047a540
                SQLINTEGER        -3 (SQL_NTS)

[000123.361764]
python          7FFF7876C180 ENTER SQLGetDiagRec
                SQLSMALLINT       3 (SQL_HANDLE_STMT)
                SQLHSTMT          0x10045c0b0
                SQLSMALLINT       1
                SQLCHAR         * 0x7fff5fbfeebc
                SQLINTEGER      * 0x7fff5fbfeec4
                SQLCHAR         * 0x7fff5fbfeed0
                SQLSMALLINT       1023
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeec2

[000123.361849]
python          7FFF7876C180 EXIT  SQLGetDiagRec with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                SQLSMALLINT       3 (SQL_HANDLE_STMT)
                SQLHSTMT          0x10045c0b0
                SQLSMALLINT       1
                SQLCHAR         * 0x7fff5fbfeebc
                          | 42000                                    |
                SQLINTEGER      * 0x7fff5fbfeec4 (102)
                SQLCHAR         * 0x7fff5fbfeed0
                          | [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax ne |
                          | ar '�'.                                |
                SQLSMALLINT       1023
                SQLSMALLINT     * 0x7fff5fbfeec2 (49)
```

FreeTDS log:

```
token.c:2355:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
util.c:156:Changed query state from READING to IDLE
token.c:2370:                rows_affected = 0
odbc.c:1454:SQLAllocHandle(3, 0x1004caad0, 0x10045c1c8)
odbc.c:1615:_SQLAllocStmt(0x1004caad0, 0x10045c1c8)
odbc.c:4388:SQLGetStmtAttr(0x1004cb550, 10010, 0x1004ab428, 0, 0x0)
odbc.c:4388:SQLGetStmtAttr(0x1004cb550, 10011, 0x1004ca118, 0, 0x0)
odbc.c:4388:SQLGetStmtAttr(0x1004cb550, 10012, 0x1004ca158, 0, 0x0)
odbc.c:4388:SQLGetStmtAttr(0x1004cb550, 10013, 0x1004cb6b8, 0, 0x0)
odbc.c:4154:SQLFreeStmt(0x1004cb550, 0)
odbc.c:4075:_SQLFreeStmt(0x1004cb550, 0, 0)
odbc.c:3463:SQLExecDirect(0x1004cb550, 0x100434950, -3)
prepare_query.c:203:parsing 0 parameters
odbc.c:3211:_SQLExecute(0x1004cb550)
odbc.c:3216:_SQLExecute() starting with state 0
mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
util.c:156:Changed query state from IDLE to QUERYING
write.c:140:tds_put_string converting 30 bytes of "??????????????????????????????"
write.c:168:tds_put_string wrote 12 bytes
util.c:156:Changed query state from QUERYING to PENDING
net.c:741:Sending packet
0000 01 01 00 14 00 00 01 00-fd ff fd ff fd ff fd ff |........ ????????|
0010 fd ff fd ff            -                        |????|

token.c:540:tds_process_tokens(0x1004b7c90, 0x7fff5fbff1b4, 0x7fff5fbff1b0, 0x6914)
util.c:156:Changed query state from PENDING to READING
net.c:555:Received header
0000 04 01 00 6a 00 42 01 00-                        |...j.B..|

net.c:609:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 6a 00 42 01 00-aa 56 00 66 00 00 00 01 |...j.B.. ?V.f....|
0010 0f 1a 00 49 00 6e 00 63-00 6f 00 72 00 72 00 65 |...I.n.c .o.r.r.e|
0020 00 63 00 74 00 20 00 73-00 79 00 6e 00 74 00 61 |.c.t. .s .y.n.t.a|
0030 00 78 00 20 00 6e 00 65-00 61 00 72 00 20 00 27 |.x. .n.e .a.r. .'|
0040 00 fd ff 27 00 2e 00 0b-43 00 4f 00 4c 00 4f 00 |.??'.... C.O.L.O.|
0050 2d 00 53 00 51 00 4c 00-2d 00 30 00 32 00 00 01 |-.S.Q.L. -.0.2...|
0060 00 fd 02 00 fd 00 00 00-00 00                   |.?..?... ..|

token.c:555:processing result tokens.  marker is  aa(ERROR)
token.c:122:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is aa(ERROR)
token.c:2588:tds_process_msg() reading message 102 from server
token.c:2661:tds_process_msg() calling client msg handler
odbc.c:2270:msgno 102 20003
token.c:2674:tds_process_msg() returning TDS_SUCCEED
token.c:555:processing result tokens.  marker is  fd(DONE)
token.c:2339:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
        was_cancelled = 0
        error = 1
        done_count_valid = 0
token.c:2355:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
util.c:156:Changed query state from READING to IDLE
token.c:2370:                rows_affected = 0
util.c:104:logic error: cannot change query state from IDLE to PENDING
odbc.c:3534:odbc_process_tokens: tds_process_tokens returned 1
odbc.c:3535:    result_type=4052, TDS_DONE_COUNT=0, TDS_DONE_ERROR=2
odbc.c:3575:odbc_process_tokens: row_count=-1
odbc.c:3374:_SQLExecute: odbc_process_tokens returned result_type 4052
error.c:517:SQLGetDiagRec(3, 0x1004cb550, 1, 0x7fff5fbfee8c, 0x7fff5fbfee94, 0x7fff5fbfeea0, 1023, 0x7fff5fbfee92)
error.c:566:SQLGetDiagRec: "[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '�'."
```

Comment: You might consider trying [pypyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) to see if it works any better.

Comment: @GordThomspon - pypyodbc worked perfectly and it uses unixODBC out of the box! If you want to make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where `pyodbc` is being difficult (for whatever reason) you might give `pypyodbc` a try. It is a pure Python implementation that is similar to pyodbc in its usage. However, unfortunately, it no longer appears to be actively maintained (as of July 2019).

[pypyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pypyodbc/) (at pypi.org)